# Rails Community Engine plugin unit tests fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Community Engine installed fine locally on my mac, but when I try to install it on my web server, it's giving me some trouble. Here's the problem I'm having now, when I run `rake test`

```
$ [~/projects/polis]# rake test --trace
(in /home/mculp/projects/polis)
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Invoke test:functionals (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare 
** Execute test:functionals
/usr/bin/ruby -I"/home/mculp/projects/polis/lib" -I"/home/mculp/projects/polis/test" "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"  
** Invoke test:integration (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare 
** Execute test:integration
/usr/bin/ruby -I"/home/mculp/projects/polis/lib" -I"/home/mculp/projects/polis/test" "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"  
Errors running test:units!
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your paste might be truncated, I don't see a backtrace.

The first thing you should do is compare your local `gem list` to your server machine, and see if there is anything that stands out to you. Especially look at the versions of gem dependencies for Community Engine (desert, rmagick, hpricot, etc).

You can also try using Community Engine edge branch, which we're using in production just fine. See http://github.com/bborn/communityengine/tree/edge

Let me know how it goes.